# Can't resolve dependency injection in a new project in asp.net boilerplate

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, blazor-server-side, aspnetboilerplate

I added a new Blazor project in my asp.net boilerplate application then add the ASP.NET Core web project reference but I'm unable to resolve the dependency injection.

If anyone knows - please help..